# Attachments in ROS wiki not working

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Citing the ROS Wiki Attachments page:

"Attached Files
To refer to attachments on a page, use **attachment:filename**, as shown below in the list of files. Do **NOT** use the URL of the [get] link, since this is subject to change and can break easily."

However, I get a 500 Internal Server Error whenever I link that way (example [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=rgbdslam-fuerte-r3761.patch)). The [[get]](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=rgbdslam-fuerte-r3761.patch) link, on the other hand, works fine.

Who should I contact to get this fixed? The 500 Internal Server Error page only refers to `webmaster@localhost` (i.e. no contact info is provided).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52385/attachments-in-ros-wiki-not-working/) by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-15**:
Please consider this post: https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20120308.185442.3620b6de.en.html and avoid attachments where possible.

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-16**:
@KruseT: Thanks for this, I was not aware of that message since I signed up to ros-users only a couple months later. In this case, however, the attachment is legitimate because I have no control over the repository for the package and it is quite useful to users (it's a patch to get it to work).

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-18**:
If possible paste the patch online (e.g. github gist) and just add a link to that file in the wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please [open an issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues) for the ROS wiki.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-15**:
Thanks for the pointer, joq. Will do.